# filter_validate_email not working or even being detected?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I've tried all the other answers for my query on here and none of them suited my needs. I'm on PHP 5.2, and I'm starting to think that maybe this filter doesn't work on my version? I've added code below, let me know if you see anything. I've tried it with and without sanitizing, and every time it just skips over the entire clause and submits the form to the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['fname']) AND isset($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) AND isset($_POST['college']) && !empty($_POST['college']) AND isset($_POST['address']) && !empty($_POST['address']) AND isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) AND $passwordEmail == $password2){

$address = $_POST['address'];

$address = filter_var($address, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

 if(!filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
header("location: registration.php?remarks=successEmail&college=$college&fname=$fname&lname=$lname&contact=$contact&username=$username");
}

else{
header("location: registration.php?remarks=failedEmail&college=$college&fname=$fname&lname=$lname&contact=$contact&username=$username");
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I removed the duplicate function and the `!` and it still does not work.

The only addition was the moving of the '!' and the removal of the first filter.

This is the code I am now using which is still failing and taken from some of the answers given:

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['fname']) AND isset($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) AND isset($_POST['college']) && !empty($_POST['college']) AND isset($_POST['address']) && !empty($_POST['address']) AND isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) AND $passwordEmail == $password2){

$address = $_POST['address'];

 if(filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) != false) {
header("location: registration.php?remarks=successEmail&college=$college&fname=$fname&lname=$lname&contact=$contact&username=$username");
}

else{
header("location: registration.php?remarks=failedEmail&college=$college&fname=$fname&lname=$lname&contact=$contact&username=$username");
}
```

Final Edit: I copied this example I found and just changed the variable names and now it works.

```
<?php
$email = "john.doe@example.com";

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
?>
```

Comment: *"and I'm starting to think that maybe this filter doesn't work on my version"* - (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0) http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Sidenote: your `isset()` and `!empty()` can be reduced to just `!empty()`. be sure to add `exit;` after each header, otherwise your code may want to continue executing.

Comment: you also have a potential missing closing brace for your first line's conditionals.

Comment: I performed a rollback on the question, back to the original post and made an edit with the code you are now using. People visiting it, will see the answers given and ask themselves: *"That's what they're using, so why the answers?"* - In turn, potentially downvoting them. Always "add" an edit under the original question/post and "marked as an edit".

Answer (score 5):

Your `!` is in the wrong place.

```
if(filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
```

By putting it before the function name you are saying "*if the opposite of the return value of filter_var() is equal to false and the same type*". That gives you `true === false` which of course is false.

What you really mean is "*if the return value of filter_var() is equal to false and the same type*". That gives you `true !== false` which is of course true.

Or simplify it:

```
if(filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
```

Comment: Tried that, still no luck.

Comment: Then make sure `$address` has a valid value as the code in this answer is correct

Comment: It does, an echo produces it's value.

Answer (score 1):

You are using filter_var **TWICE** thats why it will always fail doing this

```
if(!filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
```

The variable `$address` has already been modified to a boolean value in the line before:

```
$address = filter_var($address, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

`$address` has the `false` or `true` value instead of the email string!

Oh, and of course, like John Conde said, you're using the `!` in the wrong place.

Comment: well that makes sense.

Comment: I've adjusted it and it still just completely skips over the clause like it's not there.

Comment: @Robmeister2015 Time to get out the *big gun* then. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Your conditionals may be failing.

Comment: @Robmeister2015, edit your question adding the new code, please.

Comment: Ok, but the only addition was the moving of the '!' and the removal of the first filter. I tried the error reporting and it turned up nothing. I think I'll leave it there guys and just build a function to validate myself.

Comment: Don't give up now, Try taking off all the `AND` and `isset` from your validation. Check that you're missing a closing brace as well.

Comment: @Robmeister2015 Remember that `&&` takes precedence over `AND`, so try and reduce your code to one simple conditional and changing those to `&&` later on, and/or now.

Comment: I checked all the braces, and all other if's after this one are accessed. It just passes over this one like it isn't there. As you can see it also includes and 'else', yet this is also not being hit.

Comment: Ok, I've solved it though I don't know how exactly.

I used this example I found online and modified it for my needs and now it works.

    <?php
    $email = "john.doe@example.com";

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
      echo("$email is a valid email address");
    } else {
      echo("$email is not a valid email address");
    }
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I found out was that the `else` was below the `}`. When I moved it right behind the `}` the validation worked.

Wrong code:

```
    if(filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

            $em = filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

   }

    else{
        echo "Invalid email format";
    }
```

Working code:

```
    if(filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

            $em = filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

            //Check if email already exists

    }else{
        echo "Invalid email format";
    }
```